# Facebook Graph API: How to find out when an Ad Group was created?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Using the Facebook Ads Graph API, I cannot seem to ascertain when an [Ad Group](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/) was created. I can retrieve the start time of an Ad Group, but it seems to always be null (probably because it is inheriting the start time from the campaign - which is ok). For my purposes, I must know the created date of each Ad Group. The start time of the Campaign will not suffice as many Ad Groups can be created under the Campaign over time.

Is there any field which will help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Read" section of the API documentation has a 'created_time' parameter which is probably what you want.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/#read